# Massive replacement of data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling with an easy task: I need to write a short script that:

1) Checks for blank cells in a dataframe

2) Replace the blank cells with "1" and all the others with "0"

So basically I imagine to have something like this (df is my dataframe):

```
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):  #where i is the number of rows
  for x in range(0, (len(df).columns)-1):    # x is the number of columns
     if pd.isnull(df.iloc[i,x]):
       df.iloc[i,x]==1
     else:
       df.iloc[i,x]==0
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you all

Comment: Can you create a small dataframe in this question?  Are your blanks, np.nan or empty strings ('')?

Comment: yes sorry for not being very specific. If I execute the code "a=pd.isnull(df.iloc[78,0])" I get "TRUE" as result. I assume this means these are np.nan

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df.isnull().astype(int)
```

or

```
(df == '').astype(int)
```

Comment: Empty lists, empty sets, empty strings evaluate to False in a Boolean context. So you could do ~df.astype(bool)